# JavaFX: what is the difference between EventHandler and EventFilter?

Tags: java, events

I've been googling for a while and I found that basicly, some web pages says there are no big differences. Except for some points:

1. `EventFilter` is executed before `EventHandler`
2. `EventFilter` is not sensible to `event.Consume();`
   Let me see If I've understood it:
   Lets say I have:

   `Button b= new Button("Test");
   b.addEventHandler(.....){...};
   b.addEventFilter(......){...};`

Let's say they are both "linked" to an `MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED`; then, `EventFilter`'s code will be the first to be executed!?

Let's say, now, I have:

```
Button b= new Button("Test");
b.addEventHandler(.....);
b.addEventFilter(......){
  //some code
  event.consume();
}; // First filter
b.addEventFilter(......){
  //some other code
  event.consume();
}; // Second filter
```

In this case, boath `EventFilter`s will be executed but the `EventHandler` will not. Right?

Are there any other things to know? Are there situations where I should prefere one or other? should I sometimes use them together in order to solve some problems?

Thank you!

Answer (score 34):

Whenever an event happens, it follows a process to determine which node in the scene graph should handle the event. The process takes these steps:

- Target selection
- Route construction
- Event capturing <- filters are triggered here
- Event bubbling <- handlers are triggered here

**Target Selection** Say that your scene contains a pane with a circle. If you click on the circle, the circle becomes the event target.

**Route Construction** Next, JavaFX creates a route (or an event dispatch chain). In our example the chain would look like `stage -> scene -> pane -> circle`

**Event Capturing** The event gets carried through every event filter on the chain. As soon as one of the filters calls `consume()`, the chain stops and that node becomes the target. If no filter calls `consume()` the end of the chain (the circle) remains the target.

**Event Bubbling** Next, the event get pushed through the chain again, but this time from the event target to the stage. So if the pane event filter called `consume()`, the following event handlers will be hit: `pane -> scene -> stage`

So the difference is not only when these handlers get activated, but also that event filters can prevent child nodes from receiving events.

Answer (score 4):

As I know JavaFX **EventFilter** can be one or many for a single node and can be single for many nodes.
**EventFilter** enable you to handle an event during the event *capturing phase* but the event handler handle events during the event *bubbling phase*.

So EventFilter is executed before the EventHandler.

[java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/filters.htm)

Answer (score 2):

I do not fully understand your question, but I found this on the oracle docs:

*The primary difference between a filter and a handler is when each one is executed.*

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/processing.htm

Answer (score 0):

When you are registering any event like(button.setOnAction(new Clicker())) here starting/first Source of event will be stage and Target will be button. Now stage will delegate that event to Scene and scene will delegate to root Node and so on.finally button will get event. Here Clicker is a handler that will consume that event. If we want to track that event before handling then "Event Filter" comes into the picture. here we can track that event. After tracking once we consume that event then this will not delegate further. If we are not consuming, this will delegate to direct/immediate child node. After tracking If you want to fire some other event then we can call fireEvent(...) method.
for more visit oracle documentation
[a link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/events.htm)!

Answer (score 0):

There should be a "logical" difference.
The filter should be used when, for some reason, we want to prevent the management of the event planned in the handler's code and to stop his propagation.
In fact, as you have rightly pointed out, marking as "consumed" the event means that the event handler must not be launched.
It the Oracle docs (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/filters.htm) we can read:

> Event filters are typically used on a branch node of the event
>   dispatch chain and are called during the event capturing phase of
>   event handling. Use a filter to perform actions such as overriding an
>   event response or blocking an event from reaching its destination.

Answer (score 0):

An event filter is an event handler - being set to handle an event before it gets to the node. You cannot create an EventFilter.

`node.addEventFilter(EventType, eventFilter)` - Where evenFilter is a EventHandler object!

You can take a look at this where you can use it to block/"override" certain inherent input controls already defined in nodes such as TextArea: [How to consume a TAB/Enter KeyPressed on the TextArea, and replace with focustraversal or enter key without using internal API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731195/how-to-consume-a-tab-enter-keypressed-on-the-textarea-and-replace-with-focustra)