# TreeView - Intercept branchExpandedEvent before expand

Tags: javafx

How to execute some task BEFORE the TreeItem has been expanded?

I mean, when the node has been clicked to be expanded and before it has actually expanded.

It seems that doing the following will execute tasks AFTER the branch has been expanded :

```java
treeItem.addEventHandler(TreeItem.branchExpandedEvent(), e -> {
    // tasks will be executed AFTER the treeItem branch has been expanded
});
```

---

With the design suggested by @James_D, using a property and a listener to check if the children of the tree item are loaded is the key.

I had to use this in some specific cases as well, i.e. not only while expanding the tree item but to customize the context menu on the tree item, and I didn't want to keep the listener attached to the TreeItem. So I created, in addition to the behavior suggested in the accepted answer, a custom self-removal listener to this property so I can use it in any "just-in-time" processes.

```
public class ChildrenLoadedListener implements ChangeListener<Boolean> {

    private final CustomTreeItem customTreeItem;

    private final Runnable r;

    public ChildrenLoadedListener(CustomTreeItem customTreeItem, Runnable r) {
        this.customTreeItem = customTreeItem;
        this.r = r;
    }

    @Override
    public void changed(
        ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue,
        Boolean aBoolean,
        Boolean t1
    ) {
        if (t1) {
            r.run();
            customTreeItem.loadedProperty().removeListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage for example in a method that will expand all children of a particular type :

```
private void ifChildrenIsThisTypeThenExpand(CustomTreeItem customTreeItem) {
    if (customTreeItem.getValue().isTheTypeThatNeedToBeExpanded()) {
        customTreeItem.loadedProperty().addListener(
            new ChildrenLoadedListener(
                customTreeItem, 
                () -> {
                    customTreeItem.getChildren().forEach(child -> {
                        ifChildrenIsThisTypeThenExpand(
                            (CustomTreeItem) child
                        );
                   });
                }
            )
        );
    }
}
```

```
@Override
public void customExpand() {
    // Set scene cursor to WAIT
    CustomTreeItem customTreeItem = (CustomTreeItem) treeView
        .getSelectionModel()
        .getSelectedItem()
        .get(0);
    if (!customTreeItem.getValue().isTheTypeThatNeedToBeExpanded()) {
        customTreeItem.setExpanded(true);
    }
    else {
        ifChildrenIsThisTypeThenExpand(customTreeItem);
    }
    // Set cursor scene back to DEFAULT
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into `EventFilter`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740103/javafx-what-is-the-difference-between-eventhandler-and-eventfilter

Comment: Thanks for your help but it seems [TreeItem](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html) doesn't support event filtering. I will try event filter on the mouse click of *disclosureNode* of [TreeCell](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeCell.html).

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good solution: your event filter will not be triggered by keyboard actions, for example. What are you actually trying to do? This has the feel of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: In fact I'm doing 
**1 -** setCursor to WAIT on the scene 
**2 -** loading children of the treeitem 
**3 -** expand the tree item  **4 -** restores the cursor to DEFAULT on te scene. I've based this process on the TreeItem.branchExpandedEvent but it looks like the branch expands and the process is firing up afterwards.

Comment: Are you trying to "lazy load" the tree item's child items? There is an example of doing that in the [Javadocs for Tree Item](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html). Your comment isn't very clear; you say you're responding to the branch expanded event, but part of the process you describe is "expand the tree item", which doesn't really make sense (at least, not to me). Can you create and post a [mre]?

Comment: Note that `TreeItem` now has an [`addEventFilter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html#addEventFilter(javafx.event.EventType,javafx.event.EventHandler)) method as of JavaFX 21 (see [release notes](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/doc-files/release-notes-21.md#event-handler-methods-added-to-eventtarget-interface)).

Comment: A little testing shows that adding an event filter for a `branchExpandedEvent` using the new API and consuming the event will have slightly strange effects: the `expanded` state of the tree item will still change (as will the disclosure node, which is just a CSS property determined by that state), but the tree view will not show the child nodes. It's not clear that using that API is going to achieve what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds from the comments as though you have a large tree, in which it is expensive to retrieve the child items for nodes in the tree. So the requirements seem to be that when the user requests a node is expanded, the process of retrieving the child nodes is initiated, running in the background, and the child nodes are not displayed until they are retrieved. The disclosure node should not change to "expanded" until the child nodes are available, and a wait cursor should be displayed while they are being retrieved.

Intercepting the `branchExpandedEvent` is probably not the best approach here. `TreeItem` has an `expanded` property, and the event is fired in response to that property changing, so by the time the event is even fired, the property has changed. The property, in turn, is changed by the internal low level event handlers (mouse clicks, keyboard events) on the cell displaying the tree item. Trying to modify these internal behaviors in JavaFX is generally difficult and not a recommended approach.

Consequently, I would recommend here letting the standard behavior for a tree cell and tree item stand: that is, when the user requests the tree node to expand, to let the `expanded` property be updated. Add in a new property, I call it `loaded`, which indicates if the child nodes have actually been loaded. Following an example in the `TreeItem` [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html), we can initiate the loading of child nodes on the first call to `getChildren()`.

In real life, you likely have a data accessor and a service object that retrieve the items displayed in your tree from a database or other data source. For demo, here is a mock implementation of the service, which just mimics the long-running process by sleeping for a random time. The important part is that it has `retrieveTreeItemAsync(...)` and `retrieveChildItemsAsync(...)` method which run in the background and take an argument which is a function that will process the results on the FX Application Thread.

```
package org.jamesd.examples.lazytree;

import javafx.concurrent.Task;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class TreeService implements AutoCloseable {

    private final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

    private LazyTreeItem retrieveTreeItem() {
        return new LazyTreeItem(count.incrementAndGet(), this);
    }

    public void retrieveTreeItemAsync(Consumer<LazyTreeItem> whenReady) {
        Task<LazyTreeItem> task = new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected LazyTreeItem call() throws Exception {
                // mimic long-running process:
                Thread.sleep(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1000, 2000));
                return retrieveTreeItem();
            }
        };
        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> whenReady.accept(task.getValue()));
        exec.execute(task);
    }

    public void retrieveChildItemsAsync(LazyTreeItem parent, Consumer<Collection<LazyTreeItem>> whenReady) {
        Task<List<LazyTreeItem>> task = new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected List<LazyTreeItem> call() throws Exception {
                // mimic long-running process
                Thread.sleep(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1000, 2000));
                List<LazyTreeItem> children = new ArrayList<>();
                int numChildren = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(2, 6);
                for (int i = 0 ; i < numChildren; i++) {
                    children.add(retrieveTreeItem());
                }
                return children;
            }
        };
        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> whenReady.accept(task.getValue()));
        exec.execute(task);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        exec.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Here is a `LazyTreeItem` class that uses the service and exposes a `loaded` property, as described above:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.lazytree;

import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;

public class LazyTreeItem extends TreeItem<Integer> {

    private final TreeService service;

    public LazyTreeItem(Integer value, TreeService service) {
        super(value);
        this.service = service;
    }

    // Add a property indicating if this item's child items have been loaded or not
    private final BooleanProperty loaded = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    public final boolean isLoaded() {
        return loadedProperty().get();
    }

    public BooleanProperty loadedProperty() {
        return loaded;
    }

    public final void setLoaded(boolean loaded) {
        loadedProperty().set(loaded);
    }

    private boolean loadRequested = false;


    // override getChildren(). If this is called before the children are loaded,
    // load them in a background thread, adding them to the child list when loaded.
    // Immediately return the child list in either case.
    @Override
    public ObservableList<TreeItem<Integer>> getChildren() {
        if (! loadRequested) {
            service.retrieveChildItemsAsync(this, children -> {
                super.getChildren().addAll(children);
                setLoaded(true);
            });
            loadRequested = true;
        }
        return super.getChildren();
    }

    // nothing in this example is a leaf (it's an infinite tree).
    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now we need a tree cell. The cell is going to update a CSS Pseudoclass according to its loaded state. We can do this with JavaFX 20 property mapping with the following code:

```
treeItemProperty() // ObservableValue<TreeItem<Integer>>
        .map(LazyTreeItem.class::cast) // ObservableValue<LazyTreeItem> (just via a class cast)
        .flatMap(LazyTreeItem::loadedProperty) // ObservableValue<Boolean>
        .orElse(false) // set the boolean to false if the tree item is null
        .addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) ->
                pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("loaded"), newValue)
        );
```

(The complete application class including this code is shown below.)

Now we can fix the view of everything just in CSS. If a tree cell is expanded but not loaded, that means it is in the process of loading, so the arrow should stay horizontal. We can also update the cursor here, and maybe add in some other visual effect indicating that data is loading (I change the arrow to orange). If the tree cell is expanded and loaded, then it will show all its child nodes, so the arrow should be rotated (and the cursor reverted to default, and any colors changed back, etc.). Here is a CSS file that does all this:

```
.tree-cell:expanded {
    /* Just for demo using hand cursor here, as wait cursor is broken on Mac */
    -fx-cursor: hand;
}

.tree-cell:expanded:loaded {
    -fx-cursor: default;
}

.tree-cell:expanded > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: orange;
    -fx-rotate: 0;
}

.tree-cell:expanded:loaded > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-text-background-color;
    -fx-rotate: 90;
}
```

(As an aside, I could not get the wait cursor to work properly on my mac; I used a hand cursor, which is not the right thing to do, but it demos that the cursor is changing. Use a wait cursor if it works for you.)

Here is the complete application class, with the implementation of the tree cell:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.lazytree;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TreeView<Integer> tree = new TreeView<>(new LazyTreeItem(1));
        tree.setCellFactory(tv -> new TreeCell<>() {
            {
                treeItemProperty()
                        .map(LazyTreeItem.class::cast)
                        .flatMap(LazyTreeItem::loadedProperty)
                        .orElse(false)
                        .addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) ->
                                pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("loaded"), newValue)
                        );
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText("");
                } else {
                    setText("Item "+item);
                }
            }

        });
        Scene scene = new Scene(tree);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Here are a couple of screen shots, one immediately after requesting a couple of items expand, and one a few seconds later (after the data has been retrieved):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes it's not mentioned in my post but the fetch of the children needs to request the database. This design totally solved my problem and some others as well (see my edit, maybe you can comment it as well). Thank you for your answer!